# Is it portable using glClearBufferData for composite data types?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a buffer (used both as SSBO and VBO) that contains a composite data type interleaving floats and unsigned integers:

```
struct VertexData
{
    struct 
    {   
        float x; 
        float y; 
        float z; 
    } position;

    struct
    {
        float u;
        float v;
    } tex_coords;

    GLuint entity_id;
};

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(VertexData) * buffer_maxSize, nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

When I clear the buffer I use the following function:

```
glClearBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, GL_R32UI, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

It works, but since the *format* `GL_R32UI` doesn't match the actual type of the data (`VertexData`), I'm afraid that the code might not work on every machine/driver.

In the case the code isn't portable what is the right function I should use?

---

As an aside, should I use GL_FLOAT in my VertexData for better portability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buffer objects do not have an "actual type of the data". They contain bytes; that's it. It's the usage of a buffer that gives the bytes it stores meaning, and those bytes have the meaning that the particular usage says that they have. And even then, it only has that meaning when using the buffer's data in that particular way.

Your clear call sets all of the buffer's bytes to 0. If you use that buffer as a source for vertex data, and the type for a particular attribute is `GL_FLOAT`, then the bytes read for that attribute will be interpreted as storing an IEEE-754 32-bit floating-point value, in the same byte ordering as the CPU provides its equivalent type. IEEE-754 defines that a sequence of 0 bytes has a well-defined value (namely, positive zero), so this will have well-defined behavior.